# Go - Parsed serial port input using goroutines not printing

Tags: go, serial-port, string-parsing, goroutine

I am taking input through the serial port (using an Arduino) and I want to parse the data. Here is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/tarm/serial"
    "bufio"
    "sync"
    "fmt"
)


func readFirstLine(data []string, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Printf("This is the sensor data:\n%q\n%q", data[0], data[1])

}

func readSecondLine(data []string, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Printf("This is the actuator data:\n%q", data[2])
}

func main() {
    usbRead := &serial.Config{Name: "COM5", Baud: 9600, ReadTimeout: 0}
    port, err := serial.OpenPort(usbRead)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)


    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    data := []string{}
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(port)


    for scanner.Scan() {
        data = append(data, scanner.Text())
    }


    for {

    go readFirstLine(data, &wg)
    go readSecondLine(data, &wg)
    wg.Wait()

    }
}
```

The serial port currently prints this (looped):

```
{"temperature":[27.7],"humidity":[46.9],"sensor":"DHT22"}
{"temperature":[25.41545],"sensor":"LM35DZ"}
{"blink":["true"],"actuator":"arduinoLED"}
```

I am trying to use goroutines to parse the data, and print this (should be looped as well):

```
This is the sensor data: 
{"temperature":[27.7],"humidity":[46.9],"sensor":"DHT22"}
{"temperature":[25.41545],"sensor":"LM35DZ"}
This is the actuator data: 
{"blink":["true"],"actuator":"arduinoLED"}
```

However, I am **not** getting an output. The program simply isn't printing. I think it has to do with the way I am saving the data. Does anyone know how to fix this? And if it's fixed, whether this use of goroutines is the correct method to achieving what I want?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you think it is related to the goroutines? If you remove the WaitGroup and instead call readFirstLine and readSecondLine without creating a new goroutine, does it print in that case?

Comment: @eugenioy If I remove WaitGroup and remove "go" and use them like normal functions, it still doesn't work. I don't think the problem is related to goroutines, I think it is way I'm sending the data **to** the goroutines for parsing.

Comment: Your code never reaches to the part where it calls `readFirstLine` and `readSecondLine`, it is stuck in the scanner loop... see my answer for alternative structure for the program which uses channels to send the data to proccesing goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem with your code is invalid use of the waitgroup - you init it with 2 and then wait for it in infinite loop... also, your code never reaches to the part where it calls `readFirstLine` and `readSecondLine`, it is stuck in the scanner loop

I think the basic structure youre after would be something like following:

```
func main() {
    // create channels for data
    sensor := make(chan string)
    actuator := make(chan string)
    // launch goroutines which process the data
    var wg, pg sync.WaitGroup
    pg.Add(2)
    go func() {
       defer pg.Done()
       processSensorData(sensor)
    }()
    go func() {
       defer pg.Done()
       processActuatorData(actuator)
    }()
    // read from the data source
    usbRead := &serial.Config{Name: "COM5", Baud: 9600, ReadTimeout: 0}
    port, err := serial.OpenPort(usbRead)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(port)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        data := scanner.Text()
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(data string) {
           defer wg.Done()
           // figure out data packet type and
           // send it into approprioate channel
           if strings.Contains(data, `"sensor"`) {
              sensor <- data
           } else {
              actuator <- data
           }
        }(data)
    }
    // wait for all data to be sent for processing
    wg.Wait()
    // close the channels so goroutines terminate
    close(sensor)
    close(actuator)
    // wait for all data to be processed
    pg.Wait()
}
```

And the goroutines which process the data would be like:

```
func processSensorData(data chan string) {
   for d := range data {
      // do something with data
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is what I currently have:
`func processSensorData(sensor <-chan byte){
 for i := range sensor {
  fmt.Println(i)
 }

}`
And I changed the type from `string` to `byte` (since `data[0:2]` are considered bytes?) but I'm getting the error 
`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
 C:/Users/Documents/sensorRead.go:50 +0x1bb`
Why is this the case?

Comment: The deadlock is because the channels are unbuffered. I edited the answer so that the sending to the channels happens in another goroutine - that should fix it.

Comment: BTW does it actually make sense to process the data in separate goroutines? It seems to me that it makes things unnessesarily complex... I'd say it only makes sense to use goroutines if the processing of each data point takes "significant amount of time", otherwise do it "inline".

Comment: Thanks, I'm not getting that error anymore! However, there is a type mismatch with data (the variable you send into the goroutine) and data [] string. I tried to fix it by doing this: 
`data := []string{}

 for scanner.Scan() {
  data = append(data, scanner.Text())
  go func(data []string) {

   sensor <- data[0]
   sensor <- data[1]
   actuator <- data[2]
  }(data)
 }` 
which removes the error, but now it doesn't print anymore...What am I doing wrong here (sorry for so many questions, I'm really new to go)

Comment: I just copy-pasted the logic form your original code without giving it much tought... you probably get data packet as a line and each call to Scan/Text gives you single packet. So you have to figure out it's type and send it into right channel. See updated answer (also note the WaitGroup I added back as without it your main might exit pefore all data is processed.).

Comment: Thank you it works! I realize I don't have a good enough understanding of goroutines and channels yet, but your answer helped a lot. Many thanks :)